# Left padding on first item in UICollectionView with UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

I'm using a `UICollectionView` with a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to try and achieve left padding/margin on the first item in the view only. I've looked at all the instance attributes and methods for each and can't seem to find one that helps.

To be clear, I still want the view to be scrollable the entire width of the app, so simply moving the surrounding frame isn't going to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do what I want I needed to set the `headerReferenceSize` of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to have a 10px width.

Comment: This space appears at the top for me, not at the left side.